# Subtract 2 dates in Angular

Tags: angular, date

I am trying to do a function that returns weekNumber and I get an error at the last line saying that 
  "The right/left hand side of an arithemetic opperation must be type any number or an enum"

is there any solution?

```
weekNumber(d: Date) {
d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    // set thursday: current date + 4 - current day
    // make sunday number 7
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay() || 7));
    // first day of year
    const firstDayOfYear = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), 0 , 1 ));
    const  yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0 , 1 ));
    firstDayOfYear.getFullYear();
    // calculate full weeks to nearest thrusday
    const weekNo = Math.ceil(( ((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` for this issue

```
weekNumber(d: any) {
        d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
        // set thursday: current date + 4 - current day
        // make sunday number 7
        d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - (d.getUTCDay() || 7));
        // first day of year
        const firstDayOfYear = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1));
        const yearStart = <any>new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
        firstDayOfYear.getFullYear();
        // calculate full weeks to nearest thrusday
        const weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
}
```

**OR other Solution**

You can use `moment` for this issue

install `moment` library

`npm install moment --save`

```
import moment from 'moment';
export class AppComponent {
    weekNumber(d: Date) {
        const weekNo = moment(d).week()
    }
}
```